# C++ : Interpret unicode white space

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I have a file which contains text (ASCII + unicode) and I am trying to count total words in it using a C++ program. It is a requirement that I should read the file line by line (using `getline`) and then process each line to count the words within it.

So I have written the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint64_t ct = 0;
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
  while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream inputStream(line);
    std::string token;
    while (inputStream >> token) {
      ++ct;
    }
  }

  std::cout << ct << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, the above program outputs a number that is lesser than what `wc -w` command gives. To narrow down the problem, I modified the program to simply output whatever it reads. So now the program becomes:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint64_t ct = 0;
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
  while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream inputStream(line);
    std::string token;
    while (inputStream >> token) {
      std::cout << token << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I redirected the output of this program to another file. Now, when I run `wc -w` on this new file, the number is same as running `wc -w` on the original file. This means, I am reading all the words (i.e., "words" defined by `wc`) in my program. And hence, a reasonable explanation would be that one of the values of `token` that is read using `inputStream >> token` consists of some unicode character that is interpreted as a white space by `wc` program. So how do I change my program to also support such interpretation of unicode white space characters?

Comment: That's not going to be easy without external dependencies. Boost implements this as a lookup table to map each character to a given type, and then checks the type with some heuristics. Basically, you either need decent Unicode support, like Boost or Qt, or don't bother.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/spirit/home/support/char_encoding/unicode.hpp

Comment: If you are interested, the relevant task would be to convert your Unicode text to UTF-32 (check if a start byte or a continuation byte, or plain ASCII), check the code point to see if it is whitespace using a lookup table, and then use it as a token.

If that sounds involved, and a lot of work, it is, and there are many libraries that already do this for you. Boost notably is one.

Comment: There are quite a few "Space" characters in Unicode - so this becomes a map of characters and lookups.  Error prone to because of the need to test against all the fun that can come through.  I will say, from a high level, that C++ may not be the best language for string manipulations like this.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: I see. I can use boost for this task. What would be the best way to tokenize a string using boost? Doing that would be easier than using `isspace` check for each character.

Comment: @JohnElaine What's your source encoding, and can you convert to UTF-32? Checking for whitespace is easiest in UTF-32. Basically, I would get line-by-line, convert to UTF-32, iterate code point by code point and check if each is whitespace and process token-by-token. It's not pretty, but it can be pretty easy to do.

If you do not want to convert to UTF-32, you could look character by character in UTF-8: if it's an ASCII character (< 128), check against known ASCII space characters, otherwise, fill to a uint32_t.

Comment: You could try `infile.imbue(std::locale(""));` and `inputStream.impue(std::locale(""));` which should set your stream reader to the input file encoding (assuming it is the same as the system).

Comment: Or you could try using std::wstring, std::wifstream, std::wstringstream.

Answer (score -1):

You can go by either:

**A.** [Java's definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) of **Unicode (not non-breaking) whitespace**.

***or***

**B.** [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) of **all 25 Unicode code points** defined as whitespace.